# XmlReader skips elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following code to stream from a large XML file. However, some `<Campaign/>` elements are skipped. Any reason for this?

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamItem(string uri)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
    {
        XElement campaign = null;

        reader.MoveToContent();

        // Loop through <Campaign /> elements
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Campaign")
            {
                campaign = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                yield return campaign;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**:

The XML file is well-formed and has the following structure.

```
<CRoot>
    <Campaign CampaignID="136">
        <!-- other nested elements -->
    </Campaign>
    <Campaign CampaignID="137">
        <!-- other nested elements -->
    </Campaign>
    <!-- etc -->
</CRoot>
```

Comment: Do you have some sample XML that can be used to show the behavior?

Comment: It doesn't skip any element for the XML you posted... Can you post an example where it does?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I was able to recreate with xml that doesn't have white space between the nodes.

Comment: Yes, there are no spaces between XML nodes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`XNode.ReadFrom` is advancing your reader to the next Campaign open tag **(if there is no whitespace between them)** then `reader.Read` will advance to the inner text of that tag.  You need to skip the `reader.Read` after a `XNode.ReadFrom` like this.

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamItem(string uri)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
    {
        XElement campaign = null;

        reader.MoveToContent();

        // Loop through <Campaign /> elements
        reader.Read();
        while (!reader.EOF)
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Campaign")
            {
                campaign = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                yield return campaign;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you have Campaign nodes nested in other Campaign nodes those will end up as part of the parent node and not be pulled out as separate nodes.

Comment: This logic flow is what I was missing in my application. There are many examples out there (on SO as well) where the while loop uses `reader.Read()` in the check condition. This was causing my XML parser routine to miss every other element and the important fix for me was to make sure to have that `else { reader.Read() }` everywhere I have `switch` blocks to determine which elements are being processed. Thank you!