# Why is the XmlReader getting closed when returning an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader, yield-return

I have the following extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetElement(this XmlReader reader, string elementName)
{    
    reader.MoveToElement();

    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
            && reader.Name.Equals(elementName))
        {
            yield return XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
        }

        reader.Read();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<XElement> ExtractElement(this Stream stream, string elementName)
{    
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        return reader.GetElement(elementName));
    }
}
```

I then try to open a `FileStream` and get a specific element in an `XML` file using:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("My.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    var element = stream.ExtractElement("subscriptionForms").First();
    element.Elements("subscriptionForm").Count().ShouldBe(11);
}
```

However running the code results in an infinite loop due to the xml reader getting closed (`reader.EOF` being `false` and `reader.Read()` not doing anything) but when I change the following line:

```
return reader.GetElement(elementName));
```

to:

```
foreach (var xElement in reader.GetElement(elementName, ignoreCase))
{
    yield return xElement;
}
```

everything seems to be working fine. Why is the former implementation causing the reader to close?

Comment: I've always checked the return value of `reader.Read()` to find the end of the file, but I don't know if it _should_ be "more reliable" (I've never checked the `EOF` property tbh).

Comment: That would be a logical thing to do but in this case I cannot because of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909789/why-is-the-xmlreader-skipping-elements

Comment: You could use `do { ... } while reader.Read();` instead, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader.GetElement(elementName)` does not start enumerating yet. It returns an object that, once you look at what it contains, starts reading from `reader`. Since you return that object directly, and the `return` statement is wrapped in a `using`, the `using` statement causes the reader to be closed before the enumeration starts.

When you wrap it in a `foreach` loop, the `using` statement's effect of closing the reader is delayed until the `foreach` terminates, and by that time it'll be okay, by that time you no longer need the reader.