# How to read really big KML File

Tags: c#, xml, kml

So I have code that successfully reads in a kml file using XDocumnet, however, as the kml file is now significantly larger, I can't run the program without getting a System out of memory exception. Can anyone help me convert this code to a different reader, so I no longer get this exception

Here's what worked when the kml file was smaller:

```
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> CountyCoordinates = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            List<string> locationList = new List<string>();
            var doc = XDocument.Load("gadm36_USA.kml");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
            var result = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Placemark");
            List<XElement> extendedDatas = doc.Descendants(ns + "ExtendedData").ToList();
            foreach (XElement extendedData in extendedDatas)
            {
                List<XElement> simpleFields = extendedData.Elements(ns + "SimpleField").ToList();
            }
            foreach (XElement xmlInfo in result)
            {
                var region = xmlInfo.Element(ns + "ExtendedData").Element(ns + "SchemaData").Value;
                List<XElement> simpleFields = xmlInfo.Element(ns + "ExtendedData").Element(ns + "SchemaData").Elements(ns + "SimpleField").ToList();
                //var country = region.Element(ns + "SimpleData").Value;
                //var state = region.Element(ns + "SimpleData");
                //var cityCounty = region.Element(ns + "SimpleData");
                //<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
                locationList = xmlInfo.Element(ns + "MultiGeometry").Element(ns + "Polygon").Element(ns + "outerBoundaryIs").Element(ns + "LinearRing").Element(ns + "coordinates").Value.Split(' ').ToList();
                region = region.ToLower();
                region = Regex.Replace(region, @"[^\w]", string.Empty);
                CountyCoordinates.Add(region, locationList);
            }
            return CountyCoordinates;
```

Here is an example of the klm file:

```
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gadm36_USA_2">
        <SimpleData name="NAME_0">United States</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME_1">Arizona</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME_2">Pima</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-112.539321899414,31.7949981689454 -112.604850769043,31.8155326843262 -112.626457214355,31.8217906951905 -112.635643005371,31.8249397277833 -112.753486633301,31.8611507415771 -112.9423828125,31.9185504913331 -113.081657409668,31.9619903564454 -113.08381652832,31.9624309539794 -113.33349609375,32.0400009155274 -113.333587646484,32.0450096130371 -113.333930969238,32.0983505249024 -113.333992004394,32.1020011901855 -113.33381652832,32.3513298034668 -113.333892822266,32.4205894470215 -113.333686828613,32.5053520202638 -113.14338684082,32.5051498413086 -113.133605957031,32.5052490234376 -112.963966369629,32.504539489746 -112.929733276367,32.5048217773438 -112.872100830078,32.5048294067383 -112.572570800781,32.5058212280275 -112.202919006348,32.507080078125 -112.099632263184,32.5076789855958 -111.793571472168,32.5066299438478 -111.789756774902,32.5066184997559 -111.756599426269,32.506549835205 -111.73974609375,32.5069694519043 -111.721809387207,32.5064697265625 -111.672340393066,32.5063400268555 -111.65495300293,32.5067405700683 -111.587532043457,32.5069808959962 -111.567413330078,32.5069007873536 -111.567436218262,32.5018920898438 -111.471229553223,32.5019416809083 -111.464157104492,32.5018997192383 -111.446762084961,32.5022697448731 -111.262466430664,32.5030517578125 -111.222785949707,32.5027809143066 -111.20539855957,32.5026588439942 -111.154846191406,32.5027503967285 -111.154747009277,32.5114097595215 -111.098213195801,32.5118904113769 -111.063407897949,32.512062072754 -110.950866699219,32.5124397277833 -110.854629516602,32.5119590759278 -110.840507507324,32.5113601684571 -110.840469360352,32.513641357422 -110.756187438965,32.5145797729493 -110.704528808594,32.5144500732423 -110.694198608398,32.5143318176271 -110.684951782227,32.5146789550781 -110.548492431641,32.5139198303223 -110.448432922363,32.5144195556642 -110.448112487793,32.474781036377 -110.447952270508,32.4273910522462 -110.447196960449,32.270149230957 -110.446952819824,32.2551002502443 -110.443702697754,32.2550506591798 -110.44425201416,32.1711921691896 -110.444358825684,32.1657218933105 -110.446006774902,32.0804901123048 -110.448188781738,32.0800704956055 -110.448440551758,32.0668487548828 -110.448196411133,32.05179977417 -110.447708129883,31.9929695129395 -110.446952819824,31.9209003448487 -110.446708679199,31.9053897857667 -110.448127746582,31.7758693695069 -110.448387145996,31.7621917724611 -110.448165893555,31.7462196350099 -110.448455810547,31.7307109832764 -110.534072875977,31.7309474945069 -110.616989135742,31.7306327819824 -110.66438293457,31.7303009033204 -110.669212341309,31.7308082580568 -110.68376159668,31.7305297851564 -110.690216064453,31.7306003570557 -110.704216003418,31.7307624816895 -110.794136047363,31.7308502197266 -110.852279663086,31.7310104370118 -110.851821899414,31.7255306243896 -110.871200561523,31.7257328033448 -110.890579223633,31.7254600524903 -110.955726623535,31.7247200012206 -111.003646850586,31.7247009277344 -111.161399841309,31.7241706848145 -111.161209106445,31.6388511657716 -111.161590576172,31.5507926940918 -111.159545898438,31.5402812957765 -111.16081237793,31.522029876709 -111.263381958008,31.5218391418457 -111.298286437988,31.5216102600098 -111.365417480469,31.5211029052736 -111.364036560059,31.4234199523926 -111.406181335449,31.4369182586671 -111.440193176269,31.4478206634521 -111.448059082031,31.4503402709962 -111.534820556641,31.4781227111816 -111.618415832519,31.5049114227295 -111.687202453613,31.5267524719238 -111.700218200684,31.5308895111085 -111.769149780273,31.5527782440186 -111.952102661133,31.6104793548585 -112.122657775879,31.664270401001 -112.223472595215,31.6960582733155 -112.539321899414,31.7949981689454</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
```

Edit so this is what I've done, this successfully does what I want, but it is very computationally expensive and often ends up using 100% of my cpu and crashing the program

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> LoadZipBoundaries()
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> CountyCoordinates = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            List<string> locationList = new List<string>();
            string zip = null;

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("utah_zcta.kml"))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "SchemaData")
                        {
                            XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                            zip = el.Value.Replace("\n\t\t", ",").Split(',')[1];
                        }
                        if (reader.Name == "MultiGeometry")
                        {
                            XElement coord = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                            locationList = coord.Value.Split(' ').ToList();
                            CountyCoordinates.Add(zip, locationList);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            return CountyCoordinates;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can read it as stream and process it chunk by chunk

Comment: So I tried to read it with XmlReader, but it's value says {None}

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt at using `XmlReader`.

Comment: Have you looked at or tried [How to parse very huge XML Files in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15772031), [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441673) or [Automating replacing tables from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28891440)?  If you tried using `XmlReader` can you please post your attempt, that's the most natural way to proceed.  An XML sample as well, making a [mcve], would be great.

Comment: Also, simply deserializing with `XmlSerializer` will require much less memory than `XDocument`, so maybe simply deserializing to some DTOs would be enough.

Comment: Also, how big are the individual `<Placemark>` and `<ExtendedData>` XML element hierarchies?  Can each one be loaded into memory?

Comment: Yes, I believe each placemark could be loaded into memory. Mind explaining how to do that? And I've updated what i've since tried with xml reader

Comment: So I've got something that works.. but it is far from the ideal solution.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using a different approach: reading to each `<Placemark>` element, then deserializing to some appropriate data model: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5qD331.  Is this a *more ideal* solution?  You wrote that your current code *is very computationally expensive and often ends up using 100% of my cpu and crashing the program* but I can't really tell why or where that is happening from your code.

Comment: It might just be because the klm file is about 1.3 gigs and has over 30,000 elements

Comment: Well feel free to use the code from the fiddle to test to see whether that improves things.  Otherwise, since you now have code that works, it's not clear there's a question to be answered.  (Actually, you still have a bug, namely that your code will skip elements in non-indented XML.  See [XmlReader skips elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26787765) or [How to read large xml file without loading it in memory and using XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282052/3744182) for why.)